# Strapi Unit Testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, strapi

For strapi unit testing (using mysql as a database) i have followed the official documentation, and when i am running the same with **npm run test** i am getting errors like below

> my-project@0.1.0 test D:\Gerrit\website_backend\TE_MCA_DMSWEBV2
> jest --forceExit --detectOpenHandles

●  process.exit called with "1"

```
  at Strapi.stop (node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:238:13)
  at Strapi.stopWithError (node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js:224:17)
  at node_modules/strapi-connector-bookshelf/lib/mount-models.js:625:14
```

RUNS  tests/app.test.js
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-project@0.1.0 test: `jest --forceExit --detectOpenHandles`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-project@0.1.0 test script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

**database.js**

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  defaultConnection: 'default',
  connections: {
    default: {
      connector: 'bookshelf',
      settings: {
        client: 'mysql',
        host: env('DATABASE_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        port: env.int('DATABASE_PORT', 3306),
        database: env('DATABASE_NAME', 'myDB'),
        username: env('DATABASE_USERNAME', 'root'),
        password: env('DATABASE_PASSWORD', ''),
        ssl: env.bool('DATABASE_SSL', false),
      },
      options: {}
    },
  },
});
```

**test/database.json**

```
{
  "defaultConnection": "default",
  "connections": {
    "default": {
      "connector": "bookshelf",
      "settings": {
        "client": "mysql",
        "filename": ".tmp/test.db"
      },
      "options": {
        "useNullAsDefault": true,
        "pool": {
          "min": 0,
          "max": 15
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**tests/app.test.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const { setupStrapi } = require('./helpers/strapi');

/** this code is called once before any test is called */
beforeAll(async (done) => {
  await setupStrapi(); // singleton so it can be called many times
  done();
});

/** this code is called once before all the tested are finished */
afterAll(async (done) => {
  const dbSettings = strapi.config.get('database.connections.default.settings');

  //delete test database after all tests
  if (dbSettings && dbSettings.filename) {
    const tmpDbFile = `${__dirname}/../${dbSettings.filename}`;
    if (fs.existsSync(tmpDbFile)) {
      fs.unlinkSync(tmpDbFile);
    }
  }
  done();
});

it('strapi is defined', async (done) => {
  expect(strapi).toBeDefined();
  done();
});
```

**tests/helpers/strapi.js**

```
const Strapi = require('strapi');
const http = require('http');

let instance;

async function setupStrapi() {
  if (!instance) {
    /** the following code in copied from `./node_modules/strapi/lib/Strapi.js` */
    await Strapi().load();
    instance = strapi; // strapi is global now
    await instance.app
      .use(instance.router.routes()) // populate KOA routes
      .use(instance.router.allowedMethods()); // populate KOA methods

    instance.server = http.createServer(instance.app.callback());
  }
  return instance;
}
module.exports = { setupStrapi };
```

Answer (score 0):

It comes from the folder name, in the docs it sais ./config/**env**/test/database.json, but in your article ./config/**environments**/test/database.json.

Actually this is depending on your version of strapi, `env` in the new one.

In this issue you will get all the detailes:
[issue on Strapi Github](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/3524)